# Redis Keyspace notification not working for go-redis in cluster mode

Tags: redis, distributed, go-redis

I am using go-redis/v8 as a client library and its universal client to get/set etc.
I am subscribing to the keyspace notifications like the one below.

```
keyspace := fmt.Sprintf("__keyspace@%d__:%s", s.config.Redis.DB, key)
ch := s.rdb.GetClient().Subscribe(ctx, keyspace).Channel()
```

It seems subscriber is not getting any notification in cluster mode of Redis. But it's working in dev env when the Redis was set up in docker-compose in standalone mode. I was researching about this and what I found out from Redis documentation is -

> Every node of a Redis cluster generates events about its own subset of the keyspace as described above. However, unlike regular Pub/Sub communication in a cluster, events' notifications are not broadcasted to all nodes. Put differently, keyspace events are node-specific. This means that to receive all keyspace events of a cluster, clients need to subscribe to each of the nodes.

But with [go-redis](https://github.com/go-redis/redis) as I am creating the universal client with all the node ip's why the subscriber is not working as expected?